# An example of something that is not a subcomplex.

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I was reading this part in Allen Hatcher book :

[image]

But I did not understand it, can someone explain it to me with drawing please?

**Edit:**

I need a picture for the last 3 lines.

Comment: Hatcher says multiple things there. What exactly is it that you want explained?

Comment: the last three lines @Thorgott

Comment: Try using the reflection $S^1\to S^1$ which takes a point in the lower hemisphere to its reflection in the upper. Then the resulting CW complex would be like a hollow calzone, with a half arc protruding into its interior and the other half arc forming the crust of the calzone. The closure of the $2$-cell would not be a subcomplex, it need not even contain the $0$-cell if you set things up right

Comment: Can you please (if I am not silly) try drawing it to me using paint app and upload the picture as an answer @FShrike? I can not imagine what you are saying.

Comment: I am quite incapable of drawing that ; ) But the bottom line is, any choice of map works so long as its image is a proper subarc. You don't need to visualise it. It's just as simple as, the closure of the $2$-cell wouldn't contain any $0$ or $1$ cells so couldn't be a subcomplex. The closure of the $2$-cell wouldn't actually be a union of cells..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the circle with its minimal cell complex structure:
[image: circle with one 0-cell and one 1-cell]

Let's call the marked point $(-1,0)$. The only subcomplexes of this are the point $(-1,0)$, the whole circle, and the empty set. So for example take the map $S^1 \to S^1$ that sends $(x,y)$ to $(-|x|, y)$ (you can think of this as first projecting the circle to the vertical line segment from $(0,-1)$ to $(0, 1)$, and then "wrapping" that vertical line segment onto the left half to the circle). The image of this map is the left half of the circle, and that is not a subcomplex. If you glued a 2-cell using this as the attaching map, then the closure of that 2-cell would not contain the entire 1-cell, just part of it, and so it would not be a subcomplex.

[image: picture of the above map]